# Listener for Call end in Android

Tags: android, phone-call

I am developing an application in which i want to keep a track of that when an outgoing call ends.For example,If a mobile phone user dials a call and then i want to run a programming code when the call is ended.I want this only for outgoing calls.

Comment: Can you get your answer i am in same problem i want to start service when call ends. I am using onCallStateChanged() method but this method calls many times when call stats to ends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with telephony api in android .see this [link](http://mobisys.in/blog/2011/09/is-your-call-ended-on-android-phone/) its have an example for it.

http://mobisys.in/blog/2011/09/is-your-call-ended-on-android-phone/

Comment: Yes it is working fine.Its very good example of telephony manager to monitor call state.Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks Sir..But Now I have already done myself and published code on Github. Check below Answer.

Comment: The webpage is availabe. i have opened it

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Finally done my project on android call log details and I used PhoneSateListener and ContentObserver. Github Project: [Android Call Log](https://github.com/jmimohsin/Android-Call-Log-Details)

Tutorial: [Android Call Log Details After ending Call](http://www.coders-hub.com/2014/12/call-log-details-after-ending-call.html)