# Doing a task after Calling someone in android

Tags: android, call

I am creating an App which can do a task **after we make a call a particular number**. I can easily do a task after **getting a call** but how can we do this **after making a call?**...
Can anyone help here...Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825607/listener-for-call-end-in-android

Comment: How can i differentiate between receiving call and outgoing call with PhoneStateListener class