# What event is fired when the call ends in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Trying to identify the event which gets fired in `Android` or `Xamarin Android` right after the call (incoming/outgoing/missed) ends?

Comment: read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869269/how-to-get-call-end-event-in-android-app) also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825607/listener-for-call-end-in-android) using telephony api

Comment: Thanks @samir_k! It is helpful.

Comment: @samir_k: your comment is good enough for me to start with and that's exactly what I was looking for, because Android is something entire new subject for me. Can you please post this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869269/how-to-get-call-end-event-in-android-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825607/listener-for-call-end-in-android). In the 2nd link they have used telephony api for the same purpose, go through it, hopefully you will find it helpful.