# How to make multiple phone calls in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, telephonymanager

I'm trying to develop an android app which has a feature of calling phone numbers with a single button tap.

This is the basic functionality I'm trying to get:

Suppose that there are three phone numbers input by the user. By default, on triggering this function, the first number should be called. If the first call fails (due to any reason), then the second number should be called. The same happens for the third call.

If even the third call fails, then a call to the first number is made again, and the cycle repeats itself until a call is successful.

I can't figure out how to make multiple phone calls. This is how I've been making a single call, as of now.

```
private fun makeCalls(){
  val surf=Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:0$phonenumber1"))
  val permissions: Array<String>=arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,1)
     }
    else{
        startActivity(surf)
     }

}
```

I tried looking at the documentation for TelephonyManager, but I didn't understand it much(I'm sorry. I'm new to Android.).

How can I get this done in Kotlin?

Comment: Start by making a single phone call.

Comment: I did that above, and that code works. I need to figure out something similar for multiple calls

Comment: The next step is to determine when a call ends.

Comment: Can you help me with that? I miraculously manage to get that part wrong, every time.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as this tag is for problems/questions with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Comment: There are already resources online that explain how to do this. I suggest googling "android programming call end" or something similar. For example, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825607/listener-for-call-end-in-android